# Hiding the currently open modal when opening a new modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a page with two modals. The problem is that when the first modal is already open and then I open the second, the first is not automatically hidden.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!-- Sign Up Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="SignUpModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"> قم بالاشتراك الان بكل سهولة و تتمتع بتجربة لا مثيلا لها</h4>
      </div>
          <div class="modal-body"> 

        <div class="row ">
             <div class="col-xs-3 "></div>
              <div class="col-xs-3 " style="text-align:center; "><img src="img/facebook.png" class="img-responsive" /></div>
               <div class="col-xs-3" style="text-align:center;"><img src="img/twitter.png" class="img-responsive" /></div>
             <div class="col-xs-3 "></div>
        </div>
              <div class="row EnterbyMailText" >
                  <div class="col-sm-12 TextCenter">او عن طريق الايميل</div>
              </div>

               <div class="row LoginModalStyle" >
               <div class="col-sm-8 col-centered"> <input type="email" class="form-control TextCenter " id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="الرجاء ادخال ايميلك المشترك به"></div>
        </div>

               <div class="row LoginModalStyle" >
               <div class="col-sm-8 col-centered"> <input type="email" class="form-control TextCenter " id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="أسم المستخدم"></div>
        </div>


               <div class="row LoginModalStyle">

               <div class="col-sm-8 col-centered"> <input type="password"  class="form-control TextCenter"  id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="كلمة المرور الخاصة بك"></div>
        </div>

      <div class="modal-footer" style="text-align:center;">
        <button type="button" class="btn modalButton">أشترك</button>
      </div>

        </div>

        </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content --> 
  </div>
      <!-- /.modal-dialog --> 
    </div>
<!-- /.modal --> 

<!-- Login Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="EnterModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">دخول</h4>
      </div>
          <div class="modal-body"> 
        <div class="row ">
             <div class="col-xs-3 "></div>
              <div class="col-xs-3 " style="text-align:center; "><img src="img/facebook.png" class="img-responsive" /></div>
               <div class="col-xs-3" style="text-align:center;"><img src="img/twitter.png" class="img-responsive" /></div>
             <div class="col-xs-3 "></div>
        </div>
              <div class="row EnterbyMailText" >
                  <div class="col-sm-12 TextCenter">او عن طريق الايميل</div>
              </div>

               <div class="row LoginModalStyle" >
               <div class="col-sm-8 col-centered"> <input type="email" class="form-control TextCenter " id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="الرجاء ادخال ايميلك المشترك به"></div>
        </div>
               <div class="row LoginModalStyle">

               <div class="col-sm-8 col-centered"> <input type="password"  class="form-control TextCenter"  id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="كلمة المرور الخاصة بك"></div>
        </div>
          <div class="modal-footer" >
        <button type="button" class="btn modalButton">دخول </button>
        <div class="ForgetApassword">نسيت كلمة المرور</div>
      </div>
        </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content --> 
  </div>
      <!-- /.modal-dialog --> 
    </div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Add these lines of javascript to fire a callback when either modal is shown that should hide the other.

```
$('#SignUpModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $('#EnterModal').modal('hide');
});

$('#EnterModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $('#SignUpModal').modal('hide');
});
```

Working [JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JnDf5/](http://jsfiddle.net/JnDf5/)

Answer (score 1):

[This is documented behavior](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals):

> **Overlapping modals not supported**
>   Be sure not to open a modal while another is still visible. Showing more than one modal at a time requires custom code.

The usual solution is to use this third-party modal plugin instead of the one that comes with Bootstrap: https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal/

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the following for closing open modals before showing a new one:

```
$('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $('.modal.in').modal('hide');
});
```

This will work with any number of modals. This adds an event handler on all modals such that when the `show.bs.modal` event is emitted (which happens just before a modal is shown), the modal which is currently displayed (which belongs to the `.modal` and `.in` classes) is hidden.